# Is it possible to change the background color of the \tbclower in a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

I've been using `tcolorbox` to show formulas this is the code I'm using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{formula}{
before=\centering\bigskip,
after=\bigskip,
enhanced,
width=.65\linewidth,
colback=orange!30,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\Large,
title=Fórmula~\thetcbcounter,
arc=15pt,
colupper=black,
fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
height=2.5cm,
valign=center,
top=-2mm
sharp corners,
sidebyside,
lower separated=false,
rounded corners=south,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
boxed title style={
    enhanced,
    colframe=red,
    colback=orange,
    arc=5pt,
},
frame style={
    left color=red,
    right color=orange,},}

\begin{document}

\begin{formula}
\centering
Slope of a line given two points
\tcblower
$$m=\dfrac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}$$
\end{formula}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me the following box

In my personal opinion I think it'd look better a white background in the lower part but I couldn't find anything in the [tcolorbox manual](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Please don't use `$$....$$`. That's deprecated

Comment: And please make your example compilable

Comment: See "Skin Family ’bicolor’ " in the documention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `skin=bicolor` option. This enables the `colbacklower` key, which can then be set to any color specification.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{formula}{%
  enhanced,
  skin=bicolor,
  before=\centering\bigskip,
  after=\bigskip,
  width=.65\linewidth,
  colback=orange!30,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries\Large,
  title=Fórmula~\thetcbcounter,
  arc=15pt,
  colupper=black,
  fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
  height=2.5cm,
  valign=center,
  top=-2mm,
  sharp corners,
  sidebyside,
  lower separated=true,
  rounded corners=south,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red,
    colback=orange,
    arc=5pt
  },
  frame style={%
    left color=red,
    right color=orange},
  colbacklower=white
}

\begin{document}

\begin{formula}
\centering
Slope of a line given two points
\tcblower
\[m=\dfrac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}\]
\end{formula}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm... I don't think that the white background does look better, but this is my personal view