# Split slides in two with a vertical line? Equations on left and right

Tags: beamer, equations, presentations

I'm making presentation slides for presenting my research.

Basically the idea is: I need to compare two theories with each other. Therefore, I wish to split most of the slides into two halves, with some solid vertical line in between.
Then I wish to be able to write equations in the left side, and also on the right side. That way people in the audience can spot the difference very clearly between the two theories.

Is there any way this can be implemented? Right now I had the following code:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]%beamer
\column{0.5\textwidth}

\vrule{}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{description}
        \item[item1] description1 text
        \item[item2] description2 text
        \item[item1] description1 text
        \item[item2] description2 text descriptiotn text
                     description2 text descriptiotn text
                     description2 text descriptiotn text
    \end{description}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

However, the 'vrule' doesn't really do what I want.

I want some environment where the 'left half' is treated like a slide on its own, and similar for the right half. But all together come on 1 slide of course.

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If I were you I would use a simple table or `multicols`. But of course those are not answers to the question

Comment: You can use tcolorbox with side by side option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253411/is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-tbclower-in-a-tcolorbox

Comment: BTW, \columnseprule doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use the `\column` command, but the `column` environment:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\dotfill % to show column margins
    \begin{description}
        \item[item1] description1 text
\end{description}
\dotfill
\end{column}\vrule \hfill
\begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\dotfill
    \begin{description}
        \item[item5] description1 text
        \item[item6] description2 text
        \item[item7] description1 text
        \item[item8] description2 text descriptiotn text
                     description2 text descriptiotn text
                     description2 text descriptiotn text
    \end{description}
\dotfill
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```